# Can Isolation Forest be used to detect colored anomalies in images?

Tags: object-detection, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I am a bit confused about how isolation forest might work on images.
My problem is the following:

I have lots of images and on some of them there is a colored dot-ish anomaly somewhere. I would like to detect that and put a bounding box around it.
Is isolation forest a good method to do so?

Comment: Is the color itself anomalous? That is, it is never "normal" anywhere, in any image? Or is it only that this color should not appear in the particular spot? Is this spot in a fixed location in the image? How many pixels large is the spot? What is the variation in the normal data?

Comment: The colors themselfs are anomalous. They dont appear in the image normally but due to the processing of the image some pixels might have similar color. But the anomaly that should be detected is fairly large (blob of ~50-100 pixels). The anomaly is not fixed at a certain position in the image.